# Cant call 'strategy.entry' with argument 'alert_message'. An argument of '[literal string, literal string]' type was used but 'series string' expected

Tags: string, series

Within a strategy entry I would like to use an alert_message consisting of multiple "texts/webhook messages" preferrably devided by a ','. Very new to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried:
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, alert_message = ["53950ed9-a97b", "7cee069d-27e9"])

But gave this error: Cannot call 'strategy.entry' with argument 'alert_message'='53950ed9-a97b,7cee069d-27e9'. An argument of '[literal string, literal string]' type was used but a 'series string' is expected.

I was hoping it would create a message consisting of two texts separated by a comma. like so "53950ed9-a97b", "7cee069d-27e9"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.